# When I manually install a .deb file dkpg removes other softwares

Tags: software-installation

I noticed that whenever I manually install a deb package, dpkg removes some softwares (NixNote2, playonlinux & ukuu to name a few).
Do you know why this is happening and is there a way to avoid it?

I am running Kubuntu btw.

Thanks.

Comment: Each .deb file has dependencies or requirements that must be met; they can conflict though most conflicts occur when you mix packages made for different releases to what you are using (ie. 3rd party packages designed to work with multiple releases or different distributions such as debian, mint & ubuntu). Examples will allow us to be more specific; though you're asked if it's okay (unless you give permission first with the '-y' option for example)

Comment: @guiverc, you should post in an answer. Nothing much you can do apart from searching a deb that fits your distribution.

Comment: Thank you @guiverc.

Answer (score 1):

Each .deb file has dependencies or requirements that must be met.

As example I'll use `featherpad` (the Lubuntu text editor) on my current system.  You can view this online using

https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/featherpad

or via command

```
guiverc@d960-ubu2:/de2900/lubuntu_64$   dpkg -s featherpad
Package: featherpad
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: universe/editors
Installed-Size: 1382
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 0.12.1-1
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14), libgcc1 (>= 1:3.0), libhunspell-1.7-0, libqt5core5a (>= 5.12.2), libqt5gui5 (>= 5.12.2) | libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.12.2), libqt5network5 (>= 5.0.2), libqt5printsupport5 (>= 5.0.2), libqt5svg5 (>= 5.6.0~beta), libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.11.0~rc1), libqt5x11extras5 (>= 5.6.0), libstdc++6 (>= 5.2), libx11-6
Recommends: featherpad-l10n, libglib2.0-bin
Description: Lightweight Qt5 plain-text editor
 FeatherPad is a lightweight Qt5 plain-text editor for Linux. It is independent
 of any desktop environment and comes with all features one would expect in a
 modern editor.
 .
 This package contains the application files.
Original-Maintainer: LXQt Packaging Team <pkg-lxqt-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Homepage: https://github.com/tsujan/featherpad
```

The important bit here is the requirements (depends) rules must be met, ie.

```
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14), libgcc1 (>= 1:3.0), libhunspell-1.7-0, libqt5core5a (>= 5.12.2), libqt5gui5 (>= 5.12.2) | libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.12.2), libqt5network5 (>= 5.0.2), libqt5printsupport5 (>= 5.0.2), libqt5svg5 (>= 5.6.0~beta), libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.11.0~rc1), libqt5x11extras5 (>= 5.6.0), libstdc++6 (>= 5.2), libx11-6
```

Ubuntu (Canonical & community) spend a lot of effort ensuring packages don't have package conflicts; scripts pick up nearly all, but it's impossible to verify every package on a real running system.  I've been using 20.04, along with many others, since Oct-2019 so users of the system will have a stable system come release time, but end-users will still use systems differently to how us testers do.

More of an issue though is 3rd party (where the responsibility of testing is on you, or the third party who created the package), or users using packages packaged for one release (eg. 19.04) in a different release (eg. my 20.04 system).

Further 3rd parties often reduce their work and package once for debian (covering many releases), Ubuntu (covering many releases), Mint and others thus often not perfectly pairing with any one system, let alone the future when it comes to *release-upgrade* time. They saved themselves some work, by passing it to the users of those packages.

A final warning; avoid using the '-y' (yes) response to install or remove package commands.  Unless you're 100% sure you know what you'll be asked, you may be giving permission to something you don't intend.

To avoid dependency issues

- use only packages intended for your release
- never use the '-y' option unless you're 100% it's what you want
- do your homework with 3rd party packages; they've no doubt reduced their workload by passing it onto you, meaning all checking is on you. If the same package works on multiple distributions or releases expecting issues is sort of expected. Some packagers are more careful & trustworthy than other..

*fyi:  the extra spaces before my `dpkg -s` command where so the command doesn't get stored in my command `history`*